# How can I use wildcards in this prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, wildcard

I am trying to write a prepared statement for a very basic search function. Basically, I just need to to return the "title" when the title contains the search term (but may also contain more words than the search term).

I can do this in normal mysqli but not with a prepared statement (which I need for security, right?)

This works but no prepared statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT title, description FROM quiztime WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR description LIKE '%".$query."%'";
```

This doesn't work:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user, title FROM quiztime WHERE title LIKE %?%");
```

I get in log:
     PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error:

So how can I make that into a prepared statement? Many thanks!

Comment: add %% to your variable before passing it in when executing. i.e. ```execute(["%$variable%"])```

Comment: Are you using MySQLi or PDO extension?

Comment: @Dharman mySQLi

Answer (score 0):

You must use concatenation:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user, title FROM quiztime WHERE title LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')");
```

Comment: That returns  every user and title from the database...but at least it returns something, which is an improvement!

Comment: Did you try it with concat()? If so what do you pass as argument?

Comment: This worked!
`$likeVar = "%" . $query. "%";`
`$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user, title FROM quiztime WHERE title LIKE ?");`
`$stmt->bind_param("s", $likeVar);`

Comment: So you did the concatenation and pass this as a parameter. The code in the answer does the concatenation if you pass the actual parameter without wildcards.

Comment: yeah, I think I get this! Learning curve...Thanks for your help!